# The collection of (unitary representations on) Hilbert spaces is a set

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. I know that the collection of all unitary representations of $G$ is not a set, since there are unitary representations on inner product spaces with bases of any cardinality, and the collection of all cardinals is not a set. However, apparently if we only consider unitary representations on Hilbert spaces, the collection $\tilde{G}$ of these representations becomes a set, and this allows to put a topology on it for example (the Fell topology). This is mentioned in the book by Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette on property (T).
Why is this the case? I was thinking that maybe the collection of all Hilbert spaces is itself a set, but don't know how to prove that either.

**Edit:** Actually Bekka, de la Harpe and Valette restrict to Hilbert spaces of dimension bounded by some cardinal number. The same argument shows that the bounded dimension is necessary. But why is it a set then? And why the further restriction of completeness: would it not work for inner product spaces of bounded dimension?

Comment: @freakish I just realized the trick here: "Let $G$ be a topological group. One would like to deﬁne a topology on the family of equivalences classes of unitary representations of $G$. There is a problem since this family is not a set. For this reason, we have to restrict ourselves to sets of such classes. One standard way is to consider only equivalences classes of unitary representations in Hilbert spaces with dimension bounded by some cardinal number..."

Comment: Ahh, yes, indeed. Bounding by some cardinal is a game changer. :)

Comment: @freakish So we only consider Hilbert spaces of bounded dimension. Your argument shows that this the bounded dimension is necessary. But how do we prove that bounding the dimension we are done? Also, why don't we consider inner product spaces of bounded dimension instead, and switch to Hilbert spaces? I will edit the question...

Comment: Great! Follow-up question, in the same point (F.2), the authors mention that we can also restrict ourselves to the collection of irreducible unitary representations. Why is it the case? Does the condition of irreducibility imply a bound on the cardinality? For instance, if $G$ acts irreducibly on $V$, then $dim(V) \leq card(G)$?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will ask a separate question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85159/discussion-between-user404944-and-freakish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me gather all the comments into one answer.

(1) Since every inner product space $V$ can be completed to a Hilbert space $\overline{V}$ and $V$ can be treated as a subspace of $\overline{V}$ then $\dim(\overline{V})\geq\dim(V)$. In particular Hilbert spaces don't have bounded dimension and thus they don't form a set.

But the book additionally assumes that dimensions of those Hilbert spaces are bounded by some fixed cardinal.

(2) Having a bounded dimension is enough for Hilbert spaces to form a set. Indeed, for a cardinal $M$ the collection of all vector spaces with $\dim(V)<M$ is a set. That's because there is only one vector space (up to isomorphism) for each dimension (as a cardinal number). And since inner product is just a function $V\times V\to k$ then we conclude that Hilbert spaces are a subcollection of $(V, V\times V\to k)$ pairs which is a set if the collection of $V$'s is.

(3) We can replace "bounded dimension" condition by "irreducible representations". Indeed, if $V$ is an irreducible representation then $V$ is simple as a $k[G]$-module (here $k[G]$ denotes the group algebra). In particular there is a module epimorphism $k[G]\to V$. Indeed, you map $1$ to some non-zero vector. It extends to module homomorphism because $k[G]$ is a free $k[G]$-module. It is surjective because $V$ is simple. In particular $V$ is a quotient of $k[G]$. Thus the dimension of $V$ is at most $|G|$. Point (2) applies now or you can simply conclude that they form a set because all quotients of a given module is a set.

**EDIT**

(4) So there is another defintion: $V$ is an irreducible representation if it doesn't contain a proper, nontrivial **closed** subrepresentation. In that situation, just like in (3) we have a module homomorphism $k[G]\to V$ but now it doesn't have to be onto. However the image, name it $W$, has to be dense in $V$.

Now if $V$ is a normed space and $W\subseteq V$ is a dense subspace then every element of $V$ can be written as $\lim x_n$ for some sequence $(x_n)\subseteq W$. If we denote $l(W, V)$ the set of all sequences in $W$ convergent in $V$ then we obtain a vector space epimorphism $\lim:l(W,V)\to V$. Note that $l(W,V)$ is a subspace of $S(W)$ = all sequences in $W$. It follows that

$$\dim(V)\leq\dim S(W)$$

In our case it means that the dimension of an irreducible space is at most $\dim S(k[G])$. So again it is bounded by a fixed cardinal.

Comment: I'm a little suspicious about the statement that the map $k[G]\to V$ is necessarily surjective. Maybe it is true for locally compact groups, but I would guess that you can only say the image is dense (which, I think, is good enough). Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidHill the image is a nontrivial submodule of $V$. Hence it is whole $V$ because $V$ is simple.

Comment: Aren't submodules closed subspaces? The closure of the image would be a submodule, right? There is topology to consider here.

Comment: @DavidHill well, that depends on the definition of irreducible representation. Some authors assume that, some don't.

Comment: Actually, the definition will be standard. I don't have a text handy to check it, but it seems to me that there are good topological reasons to insist that sub-representations are closed (e.g. being able to compute $V/W$). Anyway, the bound on the dimension probably still holds, but your argument is probably not valid.

Comment: @DavidHill so in case image is only dense we can use general approximation of cardinality of closure:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316694/what-cardinalities-can-a-complete-metric-space-of-a-given-density-character-have This gives some bound on dimension as well.

Comment: I think that’s right.