# Dimension of vector space for irreducible representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, cardinals, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $\rho$ an irreducible unitary representation on some inner product space $V$. Is there a bound on the dimension of $V$ with respect to the cardinality of the group? If $G$ is finite, then $dim(V) \leq |G|$, is this inequality generalizable? What if we restrict to Hilbert spaces?

Comment: There is a bound on the dimension of $V$ if and only if $G$ has a closed abelian subgroup of finite index, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996058?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: Concerning infinite bounds, there are some obvious remarks. For instance, if $G$ is separable, then $V$ is separable as well.

Comment: As for the infinite bound, this was answered in my previous question: if $G$ acts irreducibly on $V$, then $V$ is a simple $k[G]$-module, so a quotient of $k[G]$

Comment: link to your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979179/the-collection-of-unitary-representations-on-hilbert-spaces-is-a-set

Comment: But the bound I give here is much better. If $G$ is nondiscrete and metrizable separable, its cardinal is $2^{\aleph_0}$... so to prove that $V$ is separable one needs to use the topology (and the fact we have a continuous representation)